# Mongodb bulk insert limit in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bulkinsert

Is there a limit to the number of documents one can bulk insert with PyMongo? And I don't mean the 16mb limit of document size for MongoDB, but the actual size of the list of documents I wish to insert in bulk through Python.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no limit on the **number** of documents for bulk insert via pymongo. According to the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#bulk-inserts), you can provide an iterable to the `collection.insert`, and it will

```
insert each document in the iterable, sending only a single command to the server
```

Key point here is that pymongo will try to do your insert by sending one single `message` to the mongodb server.

Mongodb itself has a message size limit (`maxMessageSizeBytes`), that is equal to 48000000 bytes (`maxBsonObjectSize * 3`).

So, pymongo client driver should be responsible for splitting your large message into smaller messages to fit into mongodb max size limit. But, actually it's not yet implemented. See:

- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-414
- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-419

For now, you have to handle this situation by yourself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This feature has been added.  Be sure to update **pymongo** if you're not seeing the improvement: `pip install --upgrade pymongo`

Comment: Unfortunately it stills gets all documents from your iterable before sending them so if you have e.g. a generator that yields millions of objects it'll load everything in memory before sending them in multiple chunks.