# Pymongo bulk inserts

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to insert documents in bulk. But it doesn't insert more than 84 documents during bulk insert. 
Gives me this error:

```
in insert pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: cannot do an empty bulk insert
```

Is it possible to do batch inserts, like inserting 50 documents per insert?

Comment: It's certainly possible to do [bulk inserts](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#bulk-inserts) with PyMongo. The error message suggests you may not have the syntax quite right. Can you share your insert code? Also, what version of PyMongo and Python are you using?

Comment: Python is 2.6, Pymongo 2.6.3

Comment: If the syntax is wrong, then it shouldn't insert any document, isn't it?

Comment: From your description it wasn't clear if you were able to successfully bulk insert 84 documents (but no more), or are still trying to do so. You asked if it is possible to do batch inserts, which makes it sound like you are still trying to get batch insert to work. The [code error](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/v2.6/pymongo/message.py#L205) is nominally triggered by trying to send through an empty batch. PyMongo should automatically split large bulk inserts into smaller batches, so the size of batches sent to the server will depend on how big your documents are.

Comment: If batch insert of 84 documents works but 85 does not .. can you try inserting a larger batch (eg. 90 documents)? If you insert a batch that "fails" do any of the documents get added?  Is there anything different about the 85th document in your bulk insert (have you tried not including it in the batch)?

Answer (score 6):

Check out [the documentation for bulk inserts in PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#bulk-inserts). You just pass a list of dicts to insert(). If the list is empty, PyMongo raises an exception, as you've observed.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the game here but have had good success with the bulk operations described here (http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html). The `insert_many()` method already does the necessary chunking under the hood. My workflow involved one large 'bulk insert' and then many subsequent full collection updates. Using the bulk update process was many times faster then the looped single update. However the % increase in speed varied based on the size of the input (10, 100, 1000, 1

```
def unordered_bulk_write():
    bulk_op = collection.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()

    for primary_key in primary_key_list:
        bulk_op.find({'fubar_key': primary_key}).update({'$set': {'dopeness_factor': 'unlimited'}})

    try:
        bulk_op.execute()
    except Exception as e:
        print e, e.details

def single_update_write():
    for primary_key in primary_key_list:
        collection.update_one({'fubar_key': primary_key}, {'$set': 
        {'dopeness_factor': 'unlimited'}})
```

These methods were run in an ipy notebook with the `%%timing` magic and i got the following stats. Methods were called in a map over a given chunk of randomly selected primary keys with increasing chunk sizes.

```
WITH CHUNK_SIZE = 10
UNORDERED BULK WRITE = 1000 loops, best of 3: 871 µs per loop
SINGLE UPDATE ONE = 100 loops, best of 3: 2.47 ms per loop

WITH CHUNK_SIZE = 100
UNORDERED BULK WRITE = 100 loops, best of 3: 4.57 ms per loop
SINGLE UPDATE ONE = 10 loops, best of 3: 26.2 ms per loop

WITH CHUNK_SIZE = 1000
UNORDERED BULK WRITE = 10 loops, best of 3: 39 ms per loop
SINGLE UPDATE ONE = 1 loops, best of 3: 246 ms per loop

WITH CHUNK_SIZE = 10000
UNORDERED BULK WRITE = 1 loops, best of 3: 399 ms per loop
SINGLE UPDATE ONE = 1 loops, best of 3: 2.58 s per loop

WITH CHUNK_SIZE = 100000
UNORDERED BULK WRITE = 1 loops, best of 3: 4.34 s per loop
SINGLE UPDATE ONE = 1 loops, best of 3: 24.8 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Already answered here: [Mongodb bulk insert limit in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753366/mongodb-bulk-insert-limit-in-python)

You don't really need to do bulk insert. Just do insert iteration, and Pymongo will be responsible for chunking the data into maximum byte size or collection the inserted data for some time until it reaches maximum byte size before bulk inserting it to the database.

Mongodb itself has a message size limit (maxMessageSizeBytes), that is equal to 48000000 bytes (maxBsonObjectSize * 3).

Answer (score 1):

Just maintain a flag to track weather there is something to execute in bulk operation. So you can avoid the exception and making the db call.

```
bulk_operation = collection.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
execute_bulk = False
for _id in _ids:
    bulk_operation.find({'_id': _id}).update({'$set': {'key': 'value'}})
    execute_bulk = True

if execute_bulk:
    bulk_operation.execute()
```